# ModuleNotFoundError (Could not find module in path: './translate.service' relative to '/src/app/app.component.ts')

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to angular and wanted to build a translation app but getting this error. The code is as follows:

```
 import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    import { TranslateService } from "./translate.service";
    
    @Component({
      selector: "app-root",
      templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
    })
    export class AppComponent {
    
      text: string;
      translatedText: string;
    
      constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {};
    
      submit(){
        this.translateService.translate(this.text).subscribe((result)=>{
          this.translatedText = result;
        })
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please share the `translate.service.ts` file too.

Comment: Are you sure that your translate service path is correct?

Comment: As I told you I'm new to angular so I have no idea where translate.service.ts is

Comment: Ok. Is this code from a tutorial? If so, can you send a link to the tutorial?

Comment: Juat found out that translate.service.ts wasn't even their in my files directory